# Which tables need to restore to get backup of all customers in magento 2.4.1

Tags: magento2, customer, magento2.4.1, table, backup

I am using magneto 2.4.1. Accidently I have deleted all my customer lists but I have a backup. So now which tables I need to restore to get back those all customer list.

Comment: You can find customers table easily prefixed with customers_

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Magerun 2 table dump configuration](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2/blob/develop/config.yaml).

It lists the following tables for customer data:

```
      customer_address*
      customer_entity
        customer_entity_*
      customer_grid_flat
      customer_log
      customer_visitor
      newsletter_subscriber
      product_alert*
      vault_payment_token
        vault_payment_token_*
      wishlist
        wishlist_*
      company
        company_*
      magento_giftcardaccount
      magento_customerbalance magento_customerbalance_history
      magento_customersegment_customer
      magento_reward magento_reward_history
```

If you've deleted all customers, any references from entities like quotes and sales would have also been wiped — you would need to look into getting your foreign keys back.